# MS Word -- Unable to open <link>. Cannot open the specified file

Tags: microsoft-word, http

RE: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/some-hyperlinks-to-pdfs-will-not-work-in-word/79274141-b55e-4ce1-9a37-e07f7f77c816

I'm experiencing the same problem as above, where CTRL-clicking an otherwise legit hyperlink to a PDF will raise a dialog box: *"Unable to open (link). Cannot open the specified file."*

I found one factor that contributes to Word's decision making about *"Unable to open (link).  Cannot open the specified file."*

**To reproduce the error:**

If the server sends any effectively "no-cache" headers, then Word will *"Unable to open (link).  Cannot open the specified file."*

**To avoid the above:**

If the server either does not send cache-related headers, or simply goes "Cache-Control: max-age=600" (max-age, as opposed to no-cache), Word will either open the PDF or try to get it downloaded via the default browser.

**Open-ended investigations to do (questions for you):**

- Are there any other factors?
- Should Microsoft "fix" this? Or is this a "good behaviour" that Microsoft built around the concept of "no-cache"? If so, please elaborate on what they were (likely) thinking.